# How is python assigning __module__?

Tags: python

Our code has a logging decorator that prints a calling function's `__module__`. As it happens, someone recently added a unit test that verifies the argument logged, which has revealed that when our tests are run through `poetry`, `__module__` takes on one value, while when they're run directly through `python -m unittest` the value is different.

Specifically:
A test in `$REPO_ROOT/tests/unit/foo/bar/baz/test_module.py` defines a test function.

- When run in our CI environment (via `poetry`), that function's `__module__` is identified as `tests.unit.foo.bar.baz.test_module`.
- When run via `python -m unittest`, it's `unit.foo.bar.baz.test_module`

My own opinion is, we should nix the test that checks the particular module name, because it's just human visible text and the difference doesn't matter, but it made me wonder:

How is python actually setting that `__module__` field?

Comment: I would nix the test, too, because it's an artifact of how the package is installed, not necessarily part of the code in the package.

Answer (score 1):

`poetry` is somehow configured to treat `test` itself as a package, rather than a directory on the Python search path in which the `unit` package can be found. As such, `unit` is a subpackage in the package `test`, rather than a top-level package itself.